# How to get the message content sent by the user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I get the message content sent by the user with:

```py
await self.client.wait_for('message', check=None)
```

Comment: Please, check [ask].

Comment: Hey @DankRoyaler! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Our community and platform has rules and ways to do things. You need to follow the following article --> [How do I write a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best suitable answer to be able to continue your coding. Thank you, kind regards. Omar.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign a variable to it and get the content. Remember that if you don't create any **check** then it will return the first message written.

```py
msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=None)
print(msg.content)
```

[`wait_for` in docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait#discord.Client.wait_for)

Answer (score 0):

Continued, to get the message written by the user we use:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

The variable `message` contains all the text written by the user. 
For commands we should use:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("pong")
```

More info in [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)